A WebSocket frame was sent with an unrecognised opCode of [7]] Angular | Spring boot
WebSocket Frame with Unrecognised opCode of [7] When Connecting from Angular to Spring Boot WebSocket Server
I'm trying to connect an Angular application to a Spring Boot WebSocket server, but I am encountering an error with the following message:
A WebSocket frame was sent with an unrecognised opCode of [7]

Here is the Spring Boot WebSocket configuration I'm using:
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebsocketConfig implements WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry config) {
        config.enableSimpleBroker("/topic");
        config.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");
    }

    @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
        registry.addEndpoint("/chess-websocket").setAllowedOrigins("http://localhost:4200").withSockJS();
    }

}

And this is the Angular code I’m using to connect to the WebSocket:
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterOutlet } from '@angular/router';
import { Client } from '@stomp/stompjs';
import SockJS from 'sockjs-client';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [RouterOutlet],
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrl: './app.component.css',
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  title = 'client';
  
  ngOnInit(): void {
    const socket = new SockJS('http://localhost:8080/chess-websocket');
    const stompClient = new Client({
      webSocketFactory: () => socket,
      debug: (msg) => console.log(msg),
      onConnect: () => console.log('Connected'),
      onStompError: (frame) => console.error('STOMP Error:', frame),
    });
    stompClient.activate();
  }
}

Dependencies in package.json:
"dependencies": {
  "@angular/animations": "^18.2.0",
  "@angular/common": "^18.2.0",
  "@angular/compiler": "^18.2.0",
  "@angular/core": "^18.2.0",
  "@angular/forms": "^18.2.0",
  "@angular/platform-browser": "^18.2.0",
  "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^18.2.0",
  "@angular/router": "^18.2.0",
  "@stomp/stompjs": "^7.0.0",
  "rxjs": "~7.8.0",
  "sockjs-client": "^1.6.1",
  "tslib": "^2.3.0",
  "zone.js": "~0.14.10"
}


Dependencies in pom.xml:
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-websocket</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

This seems to be related to the WebSocket frame sent from the client-side. I have tried using SockJS with the @stomp/stompjs library, but the error persists.
Has anyone encountered this issue or knows how to fix this error? Any help would be greatly appreciated!
Steps I've tried so far:

Verified the WebSocket server endpoint /chess-websocket is correctly configured and accessible on http://localhost:8080, Postman is able to connect.
Checked CORS settings.
Updated all relevant dependencies, including @stomp/stompjs and sockjs-client.

